# Building with multiple files in GO (GO1)

Tags: build, go

Does anyone know if it's possible to use the "go build" command to build from multiple files in a directory?  For example

```
src/
  file1.go
  file2.go
```

Where file1.go contains the "func main()" method and file2 provides supporting functions.  I've tried by using the following import statements but I'm getting no where

```
import (
  "file2"
)

import (
  file2 "./file2"
)
```

I'm wondering if this is a case that I need to modify the GOROOT environment variable to get this to work.  Or if I'm just being daft and missing something blindingly obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If file1.go and file2.go are part of the same package, this should work fine. You don't have to import files from the same package into each other. Their variables and functions are already shared.

If the files belong to different packages, they should be in different directories.

Comment: Yep, there was my problem, I had different package names in the two files.  Thanks for that